# Can the automatic Yii ID's be changed?

Tags: php, jquery, html, yii, yii-extensions

I am working on a project in Yii in which the client wants that there should be no indication that it is coded in any framework.

So while going through the final page source of any view generated in Yii, we can see that it automatically adds default tags for the ID names such as :

> '#yw0' , '#yw1' ,
>   jQuery('#yw0').yiiListView({'ajaxUpdate':['yw0'],'ajaxVar':'ajax')
>   etc.

So I was wondering if there was anyway to change these default values and change them to something else, for example : 'cp1', 'cp2' etc.

Is this possible? If it is, what is the method to do this?

Regards,

Comment: How about `yiiListView` then?

Comment: Every widget has a `id` property that can be set. Also, using the `CHtml` helper you can manually set the id of each element you are using. The documentation covers all of this.

Comment: How about changing the title of yiiListView then?

Comment: I agree with the first bullet point on http://drupal.org/node/766404 - although it is for a different 'framework', the same principle applies.

Comment: I agree, however the article is highly focused on the aspect of security. Here I am not referring to security being an ardent security fan that I am. I am referring to making the site more customized to that of the client's wish. I hope you get it?

Answer (score 0):

You should manually set a widget's id property, like Twisted1919 said. If you need a quick fix, you could also alter the core framework code and change [CHtml::ID_PREFIX](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.13/framework/web/helpers/CHtml.php#L21) but I would NOT recommend this.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to get different ids from Yii?

It will not be the good option to change any thing of framework until you deeply required that.

Yes it is possible to give different ids in yii.If you are using form in yii and models then you have to set property in yii models for that.